IAM Inline Policy in Cloudformation - (Truncated-Signature)
I am trying to update an inline policy that is used by a permission set in Identity Access Management. The inline policy will have 80 new permissions added under one sid. When I run the template in Cloudformation and check the changeset changes it shows me this "InlinePolicy": "(Truncated-Signature) followed by a long line of numbers.
The original inline permissions are not there and instead are replaced by what I mentioned previously. Is this an error of some sort and does it mean the original permissions will be removed should I execute the changeset?

The "(Truncated-Signature)" message in your CloudFormation changeset indicates that the inline policy is too long to display fully. This means your original permissions will be replaced with the new ones you specified in the template. If the new policy doesn’t include the previous permissions, they will be removed when you execute the changeset. Make sure to review and combine the new permissions with the existing ones to avoid losing functionality. Consider testing the policy in a separate environment first to ensure it meets your needs.
